# UIView transition is not as expected

Tags: ios

Im using the following code to animate view. Im expecting the view to fall from the top to the centre of the screen.

```
ViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChildViewController"];

    [UIView transitionWithView:viewController.view
                      duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                    animations:^{
                        viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 2, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height / 2 , 18, 36);
                                }
                    completion:nil];

    [viewController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:viewController];
    [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

This code works but the view has to originate from the centre point of the top but it originates from the left point of the top . Why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `vc1`:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initUI];
}

#pragma mark - init

- (void)initUI {

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];



    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ViewController2 *vc2 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
    vc2.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    vc2.view.center = CGPointMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 2.0, 0);

    [UIView transitionWithView:vc2.view
                  duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                animations:^{
                    //vc2.view.frame = CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 2, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height / 2 , 18, 36);
                    vc2.view.center = CGPointMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 2, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height / 2);
                }
                completion:nil];

    [vc2 willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:vc2.view];
    [self addChildViewController:vc2];
    [vc2 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to fall from top,

```
ViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChildViewController"];

    CGRect newFrame = viewController.view.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y = -[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    viewController.view.frame = newFrame;

    [UIView transitionWithView:viewController.view
                      duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                    animations:^{
                        viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 2, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height / 2 , 18, 36);
                    }
                    completion:nil];

    [viewController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:viewController];
    [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```